# Java + Spring + Hibernate: "order by" slow on production

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, google-app-engine

I have a Java Spring server, working with Hibernate and MySQL, and I have a view in my database, which I've mapped as an entity with hibernate.

The view is completely flat, no references to other entities. No fetches etc.

I can query the view using a simple select with no problems, both directly on the sql server using "Workbench", and using hql.
Locally I can also use "order by" clauses with no noticeable impact on the performance.

My problem is that When I move to a dev server, the "order by" clause causes the query to be extremely slow, which causes a timeout.
This happens only when the server makes the hql query.
I can still query the dev DB directly using "Workbench" with no performance problems.

The only differences between the two servers (that I can think of) is that the dev server is deployed on Google's appengine, and that the hibernate drivers are different.
On the local server I use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, and on appengine `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver`.

My local DB is a MySQL database, and the dev one is on Google's Cloud SQL, which is also MySQL (pretty much).

On my Dev DB I have about 28000 rows in total in the view, and on my local DB I have about 21000, so that also shouldn't make the difference.

I can add code if you think it could help. I wasn't sure where to start.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You are using mysql locally, are you also using mysql on app engine or some other datastore?

Comment: cloud SQL. I'll update my question.

Comment: Slow means at least 30 seconds for returning 25 results. I don't know exactly how long since there is a timeout exception fired after 30 seconds on Google appengine servers.

Answer (score 1):

I would enable the '`show_sql=true`' to see the generated queries, and also will use the '`GoogleDriver`' with local DB to eliminate any issues with driver.

Would it be possible to connect to DEV DB from your local workspace? if so, try that option using '`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`' to eliminate any issues with DEV DB.

if possible connect to DEV_DB from Mysql Manager and run the query directly on DEV_DB.

28K is very less count to get problems with 'Order by' clause.

### Edit

If you have not enabled the 'connector-j' before deploying to the appEngine, it will still try to use the 'mysql' driver, and will timeout eventually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

[More info.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database)

Comment: I haven't tried that. I'll return with an update after trying. Thanks!

Comment: So it seems it's not possible. I didn't find a way to connect to the remote Cloud SQL database. I did run the query directly on the dev DB and it works fine. The problem seems to happen when the server executes the HQL query.

Comment: you did not look hard enough, you can connect remotely it is there in the docs

Comment: @JarrodRoberson :D that may be true. But still, I can't find a way. I can't connect with the ``com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`` and I can't find a way to add the ``com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver`` to my project. I'm new to Spring and Maven... The docs I found only talk about the permissions needed for accessing the DB, which I have configured.

Comment: The 'connector-j' is enabled. Although I don't really know what that means. I'm also not sure what url I should pass the server in my hiberante.xml (I'm using Maven - which is new to me). But alas, I really got to leave now, so I'll get back to this only on Sunday. Thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps back and start over reading the documentation and tutorials, you are guessing and not even reading about the suggestions to learn what they are or do. You are wasting your time and everyone elses until you do that. example: `hibernate.xml` has nothing to do with Maven.

Comment: I meant spring. Thanks for the help. Great advice.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look to see if an index on the ORDER BY field exists in the DEV server but does not on PROD.  That can have a profound effect on both ordering and searching.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Actually, both views were created by the same script. No indexes were added at all to the view. I thought of maybe adding an index, which could really help it be faster. But I think I'll need to add an index for almost all the columns, which I'm not sure is that good.

Comment: You should index columns that appear in WHERE clauses for sure.  What kind of variable are you ordering by?